# How to put my put my program in the correct decimal format using the decimal format class?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am constructing a temperature table, and I am unsure how to implement the decimal format on the for loop of my program. I have already added the decimal format. Below is the loop section from my program:

```
DecimalFormat pattern = new DecimalFormat("##0.##");


String table = " Faren.  Celsius   Kelvin  ";       // Create the header
table += "\n------------------------";          // Add the heading underline

for ( double i = start; i <= end ; i += step) 

        {

            double c = ((5.0 / 9.0) * (i - 32));
            double k = c + 273.15;

    table += "\n   |  " + i + "\t   |  " +c  + "  |   \t" + k + "   |\n";

}
           table += "\n------------------------";
System.out.println ( table );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (table));
```

Comment: You should use `pattern.format(c)` instead of just `c`.
See also the javadoc of method [`format(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 0):

To format a number with a `DecimalFormat` (or in general a `NumberFormat`) you can use one of the various `format` methods. In your case for formatting a `double` you should use 
`public final String format(double number)`, i.e. for your example

```
String cFormatted = pattern.format(c);
String kFormatted = pattern.format(k);
```

Then you can use these strings in the string concatenation instead of `c` and `k`.
Of course you can format `i` as well using the same approach if you want.